# Creating a Dropdown That Refreshs the Page and Allow User to Edit Specific Parts of Database

Tags: php, html, forms, select

I understand the title may be a little vague, but, hopefully, I can explain it here.

We have a page where the user modifies certain fields of a database. The fields being modified change with the selection of a dropdown at the top of the page.

Suppose we have this table by the name of `restaurants`:

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------
| id | name       | items                                   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | fryking    | burger, fries, shake                    |
|  2 | burgertown | nuggets, chicken sandwich               |
 -----------------------------------------------------------
```

When loaded, the page should look like this:

```
[ CHOOSE RESTAURANT ] [v]


ITEMS:
```

With "fryking" selected, the user can: view fryking's items, add new items, remove unwanted items.

```
[ fryking           ] [v]


ITEMS:

[  (txtbox)   ]     [ADD ITEM]

1. burger           [DELETE]
2. fries            [DELETE]
3. shake            [DELETE]
```

Once a restaurant has been selected, the user should be able to add, delete, etc. without the dropdown reverting to "SELECT RESTAURANT" and forcing them to select it again.

Right now, we can display the appropriate information when a restaurant has been selected, but not have the restaurant remain selected after processing an "add" or "delete".

Sorry I couldn't explain this any better. I know this has been done 1000 times on other sites, so someone must understand what I'm looking for.

Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Many thanks,

Justian Meyer

EDIT:

Here's how the deletes are being handled (each in their separate forms).

```
$page = str_replace('%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);    

...

<form method="post" action="'.$page.'">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="'.$i.'"> // $i refers to the value from the loop
    <input type="submit" name="delete_item" value="Delete">
</form>
```

What could I do to condense every button into one form and still process them properly?

Comment: Explain the 'add' and 'delete' processing. AJAX, form post?

Comment: @Steve: Form post. We have statements such as: `if (isset($_POST['delete_company']))` to handle these submissions.

Comment: @justien that makes things harder to understand lol

Comment: if everything is a post on the same page, why do you need to have a different form for deletes than you do for the add items?  with the name attribute of an HTML element you can see who performed the postback and decide what to do with it.  So you have an if/else statement that says ... if (delete) { } else if (add) { } else { }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript:
- set the value of the drop down list in the onload event.

PHP:
- set the selected tag by saying something like

```
<?

if ($_POST)
{

    $ddlRestaurantPersistValue = $_POST['ddlRestaurant'];
}

?>
```

and the HTML would be

```
<select id="ddlRestaurant" name="ddlRestaurant">
    // build the options here if you are doing a database while loop
    // check to see if the option value == $ddlRestaurantPersistValue and then add
    // selected='selected' to the attributes of the option
</select>
```

Comment: See, this is about what I have set up at the moment. Unfortunately, everything isn't contained within 1 form, but in many separate ones, so this value isn't necessarily passed with every delete. Perhaps I can rewrite everything to consist of only 1 form. I'll post some code above and perhaps you can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what technology you use, but in asp.net mvc i would do something like this

when performing httppost i would save the value (or id or whatever) of the selected dropdown item in a session (or even a variable in the controller) and give it back to the view after the post and set that session or model information as the default.

can you tell what technology you are using?

Comment: nevermind, i notice on the tag information you use php. I have no knowledge in this technology, but you get the idea with my little text I guess

Comment: I see what you're saying. I just want to know if my only option is to pass on this value as a hidden value with every post. For future reference to everyone else: we are using php and do not have a mvc architecture set up.

Comment: With script, create a hidden field on the form (with the selected value from the dropdown) on submit. Give it back (i don't exactly know how php works, but there must be a way) after the post. I don't know if this is the best solution, but it'd definitely work. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quietly get what you mean.

> Once a restaurant has been selected, the user should be able to add, delete, etc. without the dropdown reverting to "SELECT RESTAURANT" and forcing them to select it again.

Considering I don't get why SELECT RESTAURANT mades a comeback, why just don't select what you want with a javascript code?

You can bind an onchange listener

Comment: I have an onchange listener, but I want to know the best way to pass on the value. It's a little complicated because every delete, add, etc. gets contained in its own form. I could make it a hidden value that gets passed, but that could get pretty messy.

Comment: you should edit your question and try to explain it better. Maybe post something on jsfiddle

Comment: Yeah, I apologize for that. I just don't know any better way to word it. I wish I could post the entire source code, but certain restrictions bar me from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think something like this is best handled via AJAX calls, but I won't suggest you re-write the page just to fix one problem.

You are going to have to tell your form processor what the current restaurant is, so it can be set correctly after the save. Assuming you have many forms on the page for a good reason, you are going to have to suck it up and put a hidden `restaurant` input in every form. Update them all when the user changes the restaurant value (via javascript) and reset the restaurant when building the page after the save.